# Cant call same function twice in same php page

Tags: php

I'm trying to call my function `selectuniversal();` twice in the same page, but I only get results from the first call(or the secound if I disable 1st call).

My function is:
[ func.php ]

```
<?php
global $mycon;
$mycon = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','db');
$mycon->set_charset('utf8');
class IDfun{

public function selectuniversal($tabela,$celula1,$celula2,$celulaordem,$ordem)
  {
    global $mycon;

    $IDquery = 'SELECT '.$celula1.','.$celula2.' FROM '.$tabela.' ORDER BY '.$celulaordem.' '.$ordem;
    $IDresultado= mysqli_query($mycon,$IDquery) or die(mysqli_error());

        do{
        $i=$row[$celula1];
        if($i>=1){echo '<option value='.$row[$celula1].'>'.$row[$celula2].'</option>';}
        } while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($IDresultado));
    $mycon->close();
    }

}

?>
```

In my [index.php]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
<?php 
include("func.php");
$IDfun=new IDfun;
?>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sem título</title>
</head>

<body>
<select id="cpais" name="cpais">
<?php $IDfun->selectuniversal('pais','pid','pnome','pnome','desc');?>
</select>

<p>

<select id="cvendid" name="cvendid">
<?php $IDfun->selectuniversal('vend','vid','vnome','vnome','desc');?>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I don't see `$IDnext` defined anywhere.

Comment: sorry, I wrote wrong this function, is $IDfun

Comment: from your code in index.php it seems that you are first calling the method $IDfun->selectuniversal and then $IDfun->selectuniversal2 that doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: i have correct this in my ask, all calls is $IDfun->selectuniversal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing the mysqli connection in your function call `$mycon->close()`, so the second time you call the function the `mysqli_query` is trying to use a connection that has been closed.

Either create the connection in your function, or call `$mycon->close()` outside of your function at the end of your php file.

Comment: Thanks for the help! :D